# Can't deploy NetBeans web project to GlassFish server

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, java-ee-7

Trying to create first hello world Java web application in `NetBeans` and deploy it to `GlassFish 5` server that runs on localhost. When I run my application in `NetBeans 10` it opens web browser at dress `http://localhost:8080/intro-to-jsf-nb10/` with page with error `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found`

I was expecting that `NB` will deploy project files somewhere in `GlassFish` folder, but I can't find my `index.xhtml`.

If I navigate to `GF5\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot` folder i see default GlassFish web page index.xtml, but not my one.

How to fix this problem?

I have single `WelcomePageBean` Java class:

```
package com.samples.linkedin.jsf.page;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;


@Named("welcomePageBean")
@RequestScoped
public class WelcomePageBean {

    private String welcomeUserName;
    private String completedGreeting;

    /**
     * @return the welcomeUserName
     */
    public String getWelcomeUserName() {
        return welcomeUserName;
    }

    /**
     * @param welcomeUserName the welcomeUserName to set
     */
    public void setWelcomeUserName(String welcomeUserName) {
        this.welcomeUserName = welcomeUserName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the completedGreeting
     */
    public String getCompletedGreeting() {
        return completedGreeting;
    }

    /**
     * @param completedGreeting the completedGreeting to set
     */
    public void setCompletedGreeting(String completedGreeting) {
        this.completedGreeting = completedGreeting;
    }



    public void sayHello()
    {
    completedGreeting = "Hello, "+welcomeUserName;
    }
}
```

`index.xhtml` with content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="inputTextBox" value="Enter a name here" />
                <h:inputText value="#{welcomePageBean.welcomeUserName}" id="inputTextBox"></h:inputText>
                <h:commandButton value ="Say Hello" action="#{welcomePageBean.sayHello}"/>
                <h:outputText value="#{welcomePageBean.completedGreeting}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: You twice refer to a file named `index.xtml`. Is that really its name? Should it be `index.xhtml` or `index.html` instead?

Comment: sorry, this is mistake in text - corrected to `index.xhtml`